# Fixing docker containers that keep restarting

Tags: docker

I'm sure everyone has been in the position in which someone commits bad code, you try to deploy your docker container, and it just keeps restarting. Today I had that problem again and tried to resolve it on the app server itself. I started the faulty image using the following command:

`sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh (image name) -s`

which allowed me to enter the image, make the appropriate changes, and start the app. I thought by exiting the container and running

`sudo docker commit (container id) (tag)`

it would allow me to save the changes and deploy the updated container using my deployment pipeline. However, the container kept restarting again! I noticed that the "command" being displayed when running `sudo docker ps` for the container in question showed `/bin/sh -s` which is the entrypoint I used to fix the faulty container.

So my question is this - how should I handle this situation? Is it possible to enter a restarting image directly or do I follow the process I attempted? If so, how do I correctly commit it while preserving the docker command to start the application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this situation is to give each version of your image a unique tag.  A date stamp or a source control commit ID both work well here.  Let's say you use a date stamp:

```sh
sudo docker run -d -p ... my/image:20200513
# oops, that crashes
```

Then it's very easy to run yesterday's build instead:

```sh
# we know this version works
sudo docker run -d -p ... my/image:20200512
```

If you're using source control IDs instead, you need to run `cvs`/`git`/`hg`/`svn` `log` to find the previous commit ID, but the same basic technique works

```sh
sudo docker run -d -p ... my/image:0a1b2c3
```

If your CI system isn't building tagged images, you can at least go back to yesterday's version in source control and run that:

```sh
git log
git checkout 0a1b2c3
sudo docker build -t my/image .
sudo docker run -d -p ... my/image
```

Or, use something like `git revert` to add a new commit that undoes the bad change:

```sh
git log
git revert 4d5e6f7
git push
# wait for the CI system to do its thing
sudo docker pull my/image
sudo docker run -d -p ... my/image
```

You should not try directly editing the code in the container or using `docker commit`.  That might fix your instance of the system, but the underlying bug will still be in the committed code, and nobody else will benefit from your fix.  If you do this on a production system, your production system will be running code that hasn't gone through ordinary code review and testing processes and doesn't match your official code repository.

Comment: Thanks for the info @David Maze. We do build our containers with unique tags in the form of git tags. I ask this question because I'm developing in a unique environment that makes rebuilding and redeploying time consuming. I was hoping there was an easy way to make an adjustment in the container, then commit it with a new tag. Unfortunately, this seems to break my entrypoint command.

Answer (score 0):

The docker commit saves the running container into new tag, so we can continue to examine it again for debug purposes. So, your docker commit also saved the entrypoint change you made while running the container manually.

Ideally, you should update your changes/fixes in Dockerfile, and build a new image with updated tag, that way your entrypoint would be same as mentioned in Dockerfile.

[docker commit documentation also mentions to use Dockerfile as right way to manage changes.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)